Maximum amount of money without being able to change 2€
Let's assume you only have coins and you couldn't change $2$€ with them. So for any combination of coins, they don't add up to $2$€. What is the maximum amount of money you could have?
The solution is $2,43$€. There are exactly three ways to achieve this:

$1$€ $+ 50ct + 4\cdot 20ct + 5ct + 4\cdot2ct,$
$3\cdot50ct + 4\cdot 20ct + 5ct + 4\cdot2ct$ and
$50ct + 9\cdot20ct + 5ct+ 4\cdot2ct$

I wrote an algorithm to verify this.
What I find interesting is that all three solutions can change exactly the same amounts. I want to prove this for an arbitrary coinsystem where we can't change the least common multiple of the coins.
I checked it numerically for several small coinsystems and it seems to be true but I don't see any obvious ways to prove this.
I've noticed that many solutions vary only by changing one kind of coin into another one. In my example we get from solution $1)$ to solution $2)$ by changing $1$€ into $2\cdot50ct$ and from solution $1)$ to solution $3)$ by changing $1$€ into $5\cdot20ct$. Also many solutions are compositions of other solutions. In my example the "big" coins (bigger than $10ct$) solve the problem for the coin system $10ct, 20ct, 50ct, 1$€ and where I can't change $2$€ and the "small" coins solve the problem for the coin system $1ct, 2ct, 5ct$ where I can't change $10ct$. I'd like to add that we can get from a solution for the LCM to a solution of $2\cdot$LCM by adding our biggest coin. Similarly we can get to a solution for $n\cdot$LCM.
Do you have any suggestions on how to tackle this problem? I would very much appreciate any insights, hints or solutions you find. Thanks!

This seems like a negative variant of subset sum problem: you have a multiset $S$ of positive numbers and a target sum $T$ such that every element of $S$ is smaller than $T$ and no subset of $S$ sums up to $T$. You want to find the $S$ with maximum sum of all elements that has this property.
